# Include js withing JQueryValidation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation in my application. but now we are planning to declare all the error message variables in separate file(ErrMsgs.js) and use these variable in place of error msgs in JQuery Validation Plugin(jquery.validate.min.js).

Some How i need to include the ErrMsgs.js file in jquery.validate.min.js file, so that i can make use of Variable declared in ErrMsgs.js

I used below script in jquery.validate.min.js

```
loadJavaScriptFile("Scripts/ErrMsgs.js");

function loadJavaScriptFile(jspath) {
     document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + jspath + '"><\/script>');
}
```

but i am unable to use the variables declared in ErrMsgs.js.

Please suggest me the Solution.

Thanks.

Comment: this will help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Thanks for quick reply. Tats useful but i need to declare a variables in some other file other than "jquery.validate.min.js" and need to use those variables in "jquery.validate.min.js" file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a javascript loader such as http://requirejs.org/ or http://www.andresvidal.com/jsl. If you prefer a jQuery one then I just found this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/, it uses the jQuery ajax call but parses the result as a script on success.

Each of these allow you to execute your own code on success, so you will be able to attach it to the validator messages object, or whatever as follows (jQuery example):

```
$.getScript("Scripts/ErrMsgs.js", function(data, textStatus){
   $.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, myCustomErrorMessages);
});
```

If you try to load the script the way you are currently doing it, I don't think the browser will parse the string as javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the following in your `ErrMsgs.js` file:

```
$.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "This field is required.",
    remote: "Please fix this field.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
    date: "Please enter a valid date.",
    dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
    number: "Please enter a valid number.",
    digits: "Please enter only digits.",
    creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
    equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
    accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
    maxlength: $.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
    minlength: $.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
    rangelength: $.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
    range: $.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
    max: $.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
    min: $.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
});
```

And then include it like any other JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ErrMsgs.js"></script>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on comments that these are variables that need to be used in another place, perhaps the following will work.

```
 var msg1 = "This field is required.",
     msg2 = "Please fix this field.",

     // etc., etc.

 $.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: msg1,
    remote: msg2,

    //  etc. etc.

});

$.extend(jQuery.xyz.messages, {
    required: msg1,
    remote: msg2,

    //  etc. etc.

});
```

Comment: Really its helpful but i need to use these variable in one more file other than "jquery.validat.min.js". "ErrMsg.js" is a file which will be should be used by 2 js files "jquery.validat.min.js" and "xyz.js".Is this Possible?

Comment: @sandeep, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but I edited my answer to show how you can use a variable to define each message.  You could also use [jQuery `$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) a second time for your other function while using the same variables.